# Get Dict in Json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, json

how can get value of Nombre in RCodDepartamento?
i can get *Nombre*, *Apellido*, *FechaNacimiento* using: data[i].Nombre; data[i].Apellido; data[i].FechaNacimiento; but with data[i].Departamento return undefined
pd: i is the current position of the loop for

```
data: {
Cod: 0
Rut: ""
Nombre: "Marcelo"
Apellidos: "Martinez"
FechaNacimiento: "08/abr."
DiasVacaciones: 0
Email: ""
Clave: ""
RCodPerfil: {CodPerfil: 0, Nombre: null}
RCodCargo: null
RCodSucursal: {CodSucursal: 0, Nombre: null, Calle: null, Numero: 0, CodigoPostal: 0, …}
RCodDepartamento: {CodDepartamento: 0, Nombre: "Ventas"}
Foto: "images/icon/avatar-04.jpg"
}
```

Comment: `data[i].RCodDepartamento.Nombre` ?

Comment: Where is `Departamento`? I do not see that in the object. `data[i].Departamento` does not match `data[i].RCodDepartamento`

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guideline on posting code (which is totally missing from your debugging question) and [edit] post to provide necessary JavaScript code as well as JSON that at least look related to the question - in particular JSON shows an objects but code shows access to an array...

Comment: You've tagged this question with both C# and JavaScript. This will cause confusion as answers may go by your question title, which appears to indicate you want answers to use JavaScript, but with the C# tag, you could also accept answers in that language.

Comment: thanks taki, sorry im beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = JSON.parse(data);
let obj = dict.Nombre
for(var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++){
      console.log(obj[i])
}
```

same goes for others.

Comment: `obj` is `"Marcelo"`, so this will output `M`, `a`, `r`, `c`, `e`, `l`, `o`, which I'm not sure is what the OP is asking for...

Comment: yes i guess you are right but if there is a list in dictionary then then it will work fine. i just want to give him an idea how to track it.